# Let's get critical: May 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion

We all love [Economics Stack Exchange](http://economics.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://economics.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Why does Slutsky compensation "overcompensate" the consumer?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/5357/why-does-slutsky-compensation-overcompensate-the-consumer)

**Net Score: 10** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What does a supply+demand curve look like for fare evasion?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/4995/what-does-a-supplydemand-curve-look-like-for-fare-evasion)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [From Discrete to Continuous Time](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/5075/from-discrete-to-continuous-time)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [on economic growth and Second Welfare theorem](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/5206/on-economic-growth-and-second-welfare-theorem)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Asymmetric vs incomplete information](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/5244/asymmetric-vs-incomplete-information)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Is Marginal Rate of Substitution a multivariable function?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/5047/is-marginal-rate-of-substitution-a-multivariable-function)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Modelling Pay what you want](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/5165/modelling-pay-what-you-want)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/why-low-labour-productivity-in-finance-insurance-real-estate-and-business-ser

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [How to work out average income based on square meter of property rented](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/5134/how-to-work-out-average-income-based-on-square-meter-of-property-rented)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 6)

---

- [Why are labor, capital, and land traditionally denoted by the letters L, K, and T?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/5056/why-are-labor-capital-and-land-traditionally-denoted-by-the-letters-l-k-and)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 5)

---